# Classic ASP Update table with dynamic Checkbox values

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic, checkbox, dynamic-data

I have two tables:

1) Holds a list of propertyTypes
2) Holds the propertyDetails

The user views the page and the list of propertyTypes are shown on screen - these are checkboxes that are pulled from propertyTypes and I have a repeat region around them to display them all.

The user can select a number of these propertyTypes and I want to be able to update the propertyDetails table with that information.

I have a varchar(max) field and want the data to go into there separated by commas.  It may not be the best way, but the way we have opted for.

My issue, is how do I store the relevant ID's for each checkbox in that fields using Classic ASP?

I have bound the checkbox as follows so far, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="propertyType" id="<%=(rsPropTypes.Fields.Item("ptID").Value)%>">
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks
Nick

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
myvalue=rsPropTypes.Fields.Item("ptID").Value
<input type="checkbox" name="propertyType" id="<%response.write(myvalue)%>">
```